# Sorting error HTML

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I'm trying to play around with some code from this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kutyel/5wkvzbgt/
However when i copy it in Notepad++ and run it, this is what it displays

```
<html>
```

Id: {{result.id}}

Product: {{result.name}}

Price: {{result.price | currency}}

Added: {{result.added | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}

can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: You have to use angularjs to run this code properly

Comment: how do i use angularjs? with the code?

Comment: Google it. It's rather simple

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the code in the Fiddle has also included in it a library (AngularJs) that replaces those wierd brackets things with data.

You can check that after where it says JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

To make this code work, you need the frontend framework [angularjs](https://angularjs.org/)

Try inserting this CDN in your HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your html file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Example: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_include

Comment: Follow the getting started of AngularJS on there website: https://angularjs.org/

But I would recomend you to start learning Angular on a newer version than AngularJS. Start with the following quickstart-->https://angular.io/guide/quickstart